# Django Unit testing, unknown column error

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-unittest

I'm a Django beginner and am getting acquainted to using it, and I'm also a big believer in unit testing.

Given a sample database table `contracts` with the fields

```
parent_id  int
contract_num  varchar
start_date  date
end_date  date
org_name varchar
```

I defined a model class by using `django_admin.py inspectdb > models.py`

```
class Contracts(models.Model):
   parent_id = models.IntegerField()
   contract_num = models.CharField(max_length=10L, db_column='contract_num') 
   start_date = models.DateField()
   end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   org_name = models.CharField(max_length=100L, db_column='org_name')     
   class Meta:
     db_table = 'contracts'
```

Within the test class, I defined

```
def setUp(self):
    self.contracts = Contracts(parent_id = 300, contract_num = "1234", start_date = timezone.now(), end_date = None, org_name = "TestContractName")


def test_contracts_access(self):
    self.contracts.save()
    getContracts = Contracts.objects.get(parent_id = 300)

    self.assertEqual(getContracts.org_name, "TestContractName")
    self.assertEqual(getContracts.contract_num, "1234")
    self.assertEquals(getContracts.contract_num, "12")


    getContracts.org_name = "TestContractNameUpdate"
    getContracts.save()

    updateContract = Contracts.objects.get(contract_num = "1234")
    self.assertEqual(updateContract.org_name, "TestContractNameUpdate")
```

When I run this test, I get a database error 1054: "Unknown column contracts.id in field list".  What exactly does that mean?  The first error in the stack trace is the get call right after the first save.

Thing is, I have an exact same test set up for another model object and that one passes.

Comment: Do you have a primary key set in your database? It might be that you have to specify which one that is in your model if it is a custom field, otherwise django will look for the field 'id'. What does your other working model look like? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: concur with @mshell_lauren. Django by default will always have the primary key as "id", you can override what the primary field in the field definition, `primary_key=True`

Comment: @mshell_lauren, if you make your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to check the primary key that is set in the database. If you have a primary key that is on a field not labeled "id" (I'm looking at you `parent_id`...), then you need to set this in your model. You can do this with :

```
field_name = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

If you do not do this, then Django will look for the field "id", assuming that you have one and that it is your primary key. I think you are getting this error because it is looking for `contracts.id` which does not exist!

Check out the Django docs on [primary-key-fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) and [legacy databses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models).